# using amChart Annotations and tooltips at the same time

Tags: amcharts

We've been using amCharts in our IoT / SCADA software Mango Automation for several years and very happy with it.

I have a requirement to use Annotations on the charts. They want us to save the data for the chart and the annotations to disk so that other users can log in and also see the annotations. I'm curious to know if this is possible? One issue I see is that when in annotation mode there is no way to go back to normal view mode without clearing the annotation. Meaning I would like to use the mouse over tooltips on the chart and see the annotations at the same time.

Comment: If you annotate, you're basically just drawing into a picture (canvas) from the chart you snapshotted when pressing the export button. That's the reason you can't keep the annotations when going back into normal mode, because it's getting back to SVG rendering and discards your drawings. The feature you want would be a really nice thing, but I think it wouldn't be very easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

@gerric is correct. It's not possible to have the tooltips and annotations working together.

> They want us to save the data for the chart and the annotations to disk so that other users can log in and also see the annotations. I'm curious to know if this is possible?

For this part of your question, please see the snippet with an example in how to get and set the annotation to a chart. Ideally the chart should have fixed dimensions so the annotations stay at the same position when re-used.

Unfortunately when you try to use the buttons in the snippets, you will get an error as I am saving the data in `sessionStorage`. Take a look at http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/87180663e881a5dc909078b2c17301a5?editors=1010 to see it working. Have in mind you'll need to be in the annotation mode.

Also check the [annotation API](https://github.com/amcharts/export#annotation-api) for information about `getAnnotations` and `setAnnotations`.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 2025
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441
  }, {
    "country": "Brazil",
    "visits": 395
  } ],
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0
  } ],
  "gridAboveGraphs": true,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [ {
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits"
  } ],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "tickPosition": "start",
    "tickLength": 20,
    "labelRotation": 45
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );

$('#copy-annotation-button').on('click', function () {

    var amExport = chart.AmExport;
    
    amExport.getAnnotations({}, function (data) {
      window.sessionStorage.setItem("annotation", JSON.stringify(data));
    });
  
});

$('#paste-annotation-button').on('click', function () {

    var amExport = chart.AmExport,
      data = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("annotation"));

    amExport.setAnnotations({
      data: data
    }, function () {
      // Do something
    });
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
 width: 700px;
 height: 300px;
 font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.js"></script>

<button id="copy-annotation-button">Copy Annotation</button>
<button id="paste-annotation-button">Paste Annotation</button>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```